# Laravel - Get invalid elements from Validator

Tags: php, validation, laravel

Is it possible to get the failing elements from the input array (or indexes at least)?

Example:

```
$data = [
    ['name' => 'John', 'age' => 30],
    ['name' => 'Robert', 'age' => 'nope'],
    ['name' => ['woops'], 'age' => 10]
];

$validator = \Validator::make($data, [
    '*.name' => 'required|string|max:200',
    '*.age' => 'required|int'
]);

if(!$validator->passes()){

    /*
        Get all the failed elements.
        In this case: 
        [
            ['name' => 'Robert', 'age' => 'nope'],
            ['name' => ['woops'], 'age' => 10]
        ]
     */
    $fails = $validator->getFailElements();

    // OR

    /*
        Get failed indexes:
        [1,2]
     */
    $indexes = $validator->getFailIndexes();

    //Proceed...

}
```

The reason is that I'd like to insert invalid data in a table, so it is possible to fix those entries later...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `invalid()` on the validator to get the failed data.

```
$failed = $validator->invalid();
```

[image]

Reference: https://github.com/illuminate/validation/blob/master/Validator.php#L544

Comment: I made some tests here. The method is returning an empty array, even when there are wrong data. Using laravel 5.2 here

Comment: That is odd. Checkout the Validator.php file and see if you can experiment with what is in there.

Comment: Yes, it is there. I thought it was something with the rules at first, but they seems okay (using the same as posted here)

Comment: I made some debugging, and the array indexes coming from `messages()->toArray()` are different from `$this->data`. Seems we found a bug. I also opened a issue in their repository: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14646 . Anyway... I will accept your answer, since it appears to be correct when working with simple vectors. Thank you

Comment: To be fair, I don't think they mention `invalid()` in any of the documentation. Generally when I need something, the first thing I do is dig into the framework to see what kind of goodies I can find -- that is how I found this one.

Comment: Maybe it was because the function was buggy. I made a PR in their repository to fix it. Check it out: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/14651

Comment: @CarlosCarucce Awesome job finding that bug!

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$validator = \Validator::make($data, [
    '*.name' => 'required|string|max:200',
    '*.age' => 'required|int'
]);

 if ($validator->fails()) {
    dd($request->all());
   //do your code
}
```

Comment: That will just show all the form data. The OP wants only the failing items.

Comment: No, you aren't getting it. He wants the items that **FAIL** validation, not just to print all items **WHEN** validation fails.